# Wireless Adapter keeps cutting out

Tags: wireless-networking, hardware-failure

Okay, I'm in a situation where my wireless adapter keeps cutting out, maybe after only like 5 minutes of browsing; the more intense the activity, the more chance of a cut out (i.e. multiple tabs loading/downloading file transfer etc.)

I've ruled out problems with the adapter itself, and the computer software:

I've tried multiple wireless adapters, different brands/models; tried unplugging pretty much everything but the wireless adapter to see if it happens and it still does.

I've changed operating system to Xubuntu from Windows 8 (with a full hard drive format in-between) and it still happens.

I've tried switching channels on the router, but it didn't help.

Other devices in the house don't share this issue.

It leads me to believe that the issue is hardware related.

What could cause this, and what steps can I take to debug this issue?

Comment: How long has this problem been happening for? Have you tried moving your computer closer to the router or vice versa?

Comment: It's not far away, and it's only been happening the past couple of weeks or so

Comment: Have you tried resetting the router? Or contact your ISP to see if they see anything unusual on their end?

Comment: I have, both via the unplug method and the software method (192.168.0.1). As I mentioned, there's lots of other devices here and none of them are experiencing problems... in this case is it still a chance that the ISP needs to fix something?

Comment: What is the connection type of the wireless adapter? USB?

Comment: @Psycogeek yeah. That's right. All the adapters I tried are USB. Sorry, should have mentioned.